# Delphi Fax components? (Async Pro in XE+?)

Tags: delphi, fax

Are there other Delphi VCL type Fax Components currently being supported?  I've used Async Pro from TurboPower for years, and was curious about available alternatives that might be out there. Ideally, the component would work well with multi-line fax boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference...
I went looking and found these two which have been around for a long time but I had forgotten about:

[BlackICE](http://www.blackice.com/Fax%20C++%20ActiveX.htm)
[ExceleTel](http://www.exceletel.com/)